# How to update partial page(DIV) if the DIV loads a subpage with a redirection button?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, load

I'm confused with that I can embed a child-page into the parent-page's DIV,
but I can't restrict any actions of the child-page within such DIV.
If I push the button which is belong to the child-page, 
it will refresh whole page to the new one. Not partially updating.

My HTML is as follows:

The parent-page:

```
        < div id="container" >
        < /div>

        <script>
         $("#container").load("/child-page/");
        </script>
```

The child-page:

```
        < input type="button" name="Create" 
          value="Create" 
          onclick="$("#container").load("/child-page/")" />
```

How can I only update the parent-page's DIV without refreshing whole page ?

Best regards,
Josh

Comment: Try adding return false; in the onClick command, so it wont fire it's native "button push".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **`parent-page.html`** page should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#container").load("./child-page.html");
});
</script>

<marquee>Parent Page!</marquee>
<div id="container"></div>
```

and your **`child-page.html`** should be:

```
<input type="button" name="Create" value="Create" onclick="$('#container').load('./child-page.html')" />
```

Also you can use `\"` instead of `'`. So `onclick="$("#container").load("/child-page/")"` is incorrect!.

I used `marquee` tag to tell you that the whole parent page is not refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="container"></div>
<input type="button" name="flavor_create_btn" value="Create Flavor" />
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('input[name="flavor_create_btn"]').on('click', function(){
      $("#container").load("/child-page/");
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I just added above html to my child-page, it  seems doesn't work :(    no response after pushing the button